# Find the length of the diagonal of the largest possible cube inscribed in a hemisphere of radius $4√2 cm$

Tags: geometry

Find the length of the diagonal of the largest possible cube inscribed in a hemisphere of radius $ 4√2 cm$.

A) $12 cm$
B) $6 cm$
C) $8 cm$
D)$ 4 cm$

Solution

Diagonal of cube $= √3 edge $

Edge $ = 8√2$

So diagonal $ = 8√6 $

My answer is different from the given options. Where am I wrong ?

Comment: You can't inscribe (that is, put inside without getting outside at some point) a cube of length $a$ in a hemisphere of diameter $a$...

Comment: Worse than that, if you have a sphere (complete) of diameter $D$, the inscribed cube has its vertices touching the sphere and opposite vertices are symmetrical regarding the center of the sphere. Thus, the diagonal of the said cube is $D$. Obviously that can't be more for a hemisphere.

Comment: So how can we solve this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine the cube inside the hemisphere.

Then there are four vertices touching the "dome", and four lying on the "floor".

Consider the plane going through two opposite vertices (each) of the squares defined by the upper and lower planes of the cube.

You have then defined a rectangle of height $a$, being the side of the cube, and of length $\sqrt 2a$, being the diagonal of the square.

You know that the distance between the center of the sphere and any upper vertex is $4\sqrt 2$. But this is also the hypothenuse of the triangle defined by the center of the sphere, and two vertices of the said rectangle.

Thus $a^2+(\dfrac{\sqrt 2a}{2})^2=4\sqrt2$

and $a=\dfrac{8}{\sqrt 3}$

The diagonal is indeed $\sqrt 3a$, that is, $8$cm.