# A hemisphere is inscribed in a cube

Tags: volume, solid-geometry

Finding the [largest cube inscribed in a hemisphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143551/find-the-length-of-the-diagonal-of-the-largest-possible-cube-inscribed-in-a-hemi) has been considered here previously.  So let's consider the reverse relationship:

> A hemisphere is inscribed in a cube with an edge of $1m$. What is the maximum radius of the hemisphere ?

Obviously a whole sphere of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ can be inscribed in the cube, but could a hemisphere of larger radius fit in there somehow?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  It is expected that in addition to stating the problem, as you have concisely done here, you will sketch the context:  what motivates the problem (why is it of interest to you?) and/or what approach you have tried or are familiar with (esp. what difficulty did you encounter?).  This serves at least two purposes.  It helps Readers to respond in a way you will find helpful, without rehashing material already known to you unnecessarily, and it helps avoid giving the impression you expect others to do your thinking for you.

Comment: @hardmath & co.: I've read these hypocritical sermons a hundred times now. The OP has formulated an interesting mathematical problem, and with all probability has not invested much thought on it. But nevertheless it is a good problem that many collaborators here would like to tackle. – On the face of it my guess is that the people who voted to close did so because they didn't see an obvious solution right away.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter:  My bar for context is pretty low.  On the basis of your answer (which I've upvoted), I'll add some context myself to the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Extending my comment on Win Vineeth's answer:

Imagine a flat circular disk $D$ of radius $1$ centered on the line $t\mapsto(t,t,t)$, and lying in a plane  orthogonal to this line, such that it just touches the coordinate planes in three points forming an equilateral triangle.

[image]

Doing a little coordinate geometry one computes $$M=\sqrt{2\over3}(1,1,1)\ ,$$ and the $(x,y)$-plane is touched at $\bigl(\sqrt{3\over2},\sqrt{3\over2},0\bigr)$. Erect a hemiball of radius $1$ on the "far side" of $D$. This hemiball will then fit into the cube
$$\left[0,\sqrt{2\over3}+1\right]^3\ .$$
If the cube is required to have side length $1$ the admissible radius $\rho$ of the hemiball is therefore given by  $$\rho={1\over \sqrt{2/3}+1}=3-\sqrt{6}\doteq0.5505\ .$$

Comment: The result seems great! and In this case, the circle at the bottom of the hemisphere should be inscribed to the other three faces of the cuboid which are not tangent to the hemisphere. How to prove it? and is it possible to prove such a volume is already the largest?

Comment: I forwarded an answer below from a middle school math teacher, but I don't really understand the logic behind.

Answer (score 1):

**I forward and edit this proof from a middle school math teacher**

Note that a sphere inscribe to a cubiod is tangent to all the six faces of the cuboid, then a hemisphere inscribe to a cuboid should be tangent to at least three cuboid-faces adjacent to each other.

This means, the (sphere) center of the hemisphere locates at a diagonal line of the cuboid.

Since a hemisphere is tangent to at least three cuboid faces adjacent-to-each other, and the three cuboid faces are perpendicular to each other and they have a common intersection point, let it be $O$, we can set up a 3D Descartes coordiate with $O$ as origin, and the three intersection lines of the three tangent faces as $x,y,z$-axes.

Suppose such a hemisphere is half of a sphere with radius $r$ centered at $A$. Then the coordinate of $A$ is $(r,r,r)$; the implicit equation of the sphere/hemisphere is $(x-r)^2+(y-r)^2+(z-r)^2=r^2$.

Suppose a plane $ax+by+cz=1$ (then $ar+br+cr=1$, $a>0,b>0,c>0$)passes through $A$ and separates sphere $A$ into two halfs, one of which is what we expect to find.

**Here the $W$ is the key, but I don't really understand **
why $W$ and $a\le b, c$ can be assumed together. from the picture at the bottom, $W$ has three possibilities, for each one, we have to assume different inequalities to prove that $3-\sqrt{6}$ is the maximum $r$.

Without loss of generality, we can assume $a\le b, c$, then $a^2+b^2+c^2\le \dfrac{3}{2}(b^2+c^2)$

and it is easy to verify that point $W(x_w,y_w,z_w)=$
 $\left(\dfrac{r \sqrt{b^2+c^2}}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}+r,\;r-\dfrac{a b r}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}
   \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}},\;r-\dfrac{a c r}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2} \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}\right)$

is on both the plane $ax+by+cz=1$ and the hemisphere.

Easy to know that:

$$\left(1+\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}}\right)r\le x_w=\dfrac{r \sqrt{b^2+c^2}}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}+r\le1$$

which means:
$$r\le \dfrac{1}{1+\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}}}=3-\sqrt{6}$$

$r$ maximizes when $a=b=c=\dfrac{1}{3r}=\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{\sqrt{6}}{9}$

The results can be visualized as:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maximum radius without any doubt is $\frac 12m$

Imagine the hemisphere with the base on a side of the cube.

Comment: You can fit a hemidisk of radius $2-\sqrt{2}>{1\over2}$ into a unit square.

Comment: hemidisk? He asked hemicircle. Is it still the same?

Comment: It's the same, but he didn't say "axes aligned".